# How can blind substitution in differential equation lead to error?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In differential equations,we sometime require to substitute for some variable to get a simplified expression but sometimes the substitutions are too complicated,for example substitute $x=a\operatorname{sin}^2\theta$ or suppose $y=a\operatorname{exp}(\phi)$ blindly without seeing the domain of $x,y$.What is the guarantee that we can apply a particular substitution there?I have seen that sometimes it may happen that blindly substituting can change the result and lead you to a wrong result.So how to actually understand whether we can use these substitutions there or not?
  Also it happens sometimes that we calculate blindly to simplify an expression and suppose divide by an expression that can be zero.Then we change the solution of the differential equation,right.Can someone help me to understand why actually we do those manipulations.I am looking for some rigorous explanation behind the calculations we keep on doing blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common example I see is trigonometric substitution, mainly with definite integrals (people forget about absolute values).

For example, a substitution $x=\cos\theta\, $ in the following integral gives

$$\int \sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx = -\int |\sin \theta|\sin\theta \, d\theta$$

Where many students would just ignore the absolute value.

Another problem would be the range of the function you are integrating. In the previous example, all values of $x$ in the domain of the integrand are defined and exist by the substitution $x=\cos\theta$, and all values of the integrand are *assumed* to be achievable by the substitution. However if I were to try the same with

$$\int_0^3 x dx$$

I cannot make the same substitution, since $x=\cos\theta$ cannot represent the function $f(x) = x$ on this interval. However, if it were the interval $0\le x \le a$, where $a\le 1$, we can.

For examaple,

$$\int_0^{1/2} x dx = \int_{\pi/2}^{2\pi/3} \cos\theta (-\sin\theta) d\theta =\dfrac{1}{8}$$

Note the interval was chosen carefully, but can be different.

Comment: but how to understand in case of complicated situations where we have standard substitutions.

Comment: Can you give me an example of such error in a differential equation?

Comment: The point is, that you need to understand the question being asked. While one substitution may give a "solution" it may be worthless to the application. An example is what I provided, solve $y' = x$. If you substitute $x=\cos\theta$ you get a result that does not make sense for all possible values of the independent variable.

Comment: These are very simple situations,but there are cases in which we get very complicated looking integrals and we have to substitute like $z^{3/2}-1=x^5$ how to make any sense out of it,they are implicitly related.

Comment: $x^5$ has a domain of all real numbers, $z^{3/2}$ does not

Comment: (depending on the definition of fractional exponents)

Comment: Will you elaborate?

Comment: $z^{3/2}-1$ can be undefined if $z<0$, whereas $x^5$ is always defined

Comment: Suppose we have the DE $\frac{dy}{dx}=(x^{3/2}-1)^{1/5}$,then how to tackle this thing?I think first we have to see where the RHS function is defined,for example $x^{3/2}=(x^{1/2})^3$ which is defined if $x\geq 0$.Now since we have a $1/5$ power outside,so $x^{3/2}-1$ must be greater than or equal to 1 i.e. $x$ must be atleast $1$ i.e. $x\geq 1$.So we are trying to solve for $y=f(x)$ which is defined on $[1,\infty)$,

Comment: Canyou give some more examples of such differential equations?